# how to find type or print variable details\content in tensorflow

Tags: python, debugging, variables, tensorflow

I am following [this issue](https://github.com/AshishBora/csgm/issues/3) trying to use my own data-set with the code. The owner suggested to modify [this line](https://github.com/AshishBora/csgm/blob/master/src/celebA_model_def.py#L51) in the source code. I am very new to TF and python. I tried print and tf.Print() to see what is the content of `restore_dict`. I admit I do not understand the code line `{var.op.name: var for var in tf.global_variables() if var.op.name in restore_vars}`. What are the brackets for? what is `var for var in`?

Can anyone help clarify how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}`  is for dictionary in python. You can check more about dictionaries in python [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-dictionaries-in-python-3).

now lets check this line:  `{var.op.name: var for var in tf.global_variables() if var.op.name in restore_vars}`   What you see is python comprehension , it is popular in python and you can find a detailed explanation [here](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html).

It says loop through `tf.global_variables()` and check if `var.op.name` is present in restore_vars. If it is then create var.op.name:var (key-value) pair in dictionary.